# How to change the Start Menu shortcut action for all users in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, start-menu, windows-10-v1703, cygwin-x

I set up a Cygwin/X environment in my Windows 10 computer and it created a Start Menu shortcut for all users, named *XWin Server*.

However, I need to change the shortcut to enable TCP connections. To do that, I just need to add `-- -listen tcp` to the end of the shortcut's Destination field.

The shortcut is located in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Cygwin-X\.

But I can't change it because if I try to change the Destination directly in the shortcut in the folder, Windows asks for administrator privileges and even if I click in "Continue" icon (with the shield), the change fails reporting absence of administrator privileges.

If copy the shortcut to other folder (Desktop folder) and change it, it does change. However, when I copy the new shortcut back to the proper folder, it is not recognized as a shortcut and isn't listed in the Start Menu.

Ideas of how to proceed?

P.S.: I've done that in the past and I know that worked, but it doesn't work anymore. Windows 10 v1703.

Comment: Change ownership of that folder with command `icacls "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" /grant Everyone:F /T`

Comment: @Biswa, after I ran your command, I was able to change the properties directly in the icon in the global Start Menu folder. However, the shortcut stopped showing in the Start Menu. I opened Task Manager and restarted Windows Explorer, but the shortcut still isn't there.

Comment: Log on with an administrator account and make the changes.

Comment: @DavidPostill, it is the work computer. I don't have an administrator password and I'd rather not open a ticket asking to just fix a shortcut. I already have the edited shortcut in my desktop, but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: You could run the cygwin installer again (not selecting any packages) and when it comes to the menu bit at the end just install for you instead of all users ...

Comment: See this [article](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-fix-newly-installed-programs-wont-show-in-start-menu-search/).

Comment: @DavidPostill, it's a simple good idea. I installed the new shortcut in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Cygwin-X` and it is working. It has a blank generic icon instead of the correct one, (I'll not try to fix it right now), but it shows in the Start Menu. Thank you! Nevertheless, the question described in the title remains.

Comment: @Biswa. Thank you, but I guess the article doesn't address the problem because it is about Start Menu Search and my problem presents itself regardless of the search.